# «ПриходитЬся покупать дрова» – с мягким знаком?

Tags: орфография, глаголы, мягкий-знак

«Приходится покупать дрова» или «ПриходитЬся покупать дрова»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **приходится** покупать дрова (без мягкого знака).

**приходи́ться** — что делать? — глагол (инф.), несовершенный вид, непереходный;
**прихо́дится** — что делает? — 3 л., ед. ч., действ. залог, наст. вр.

Если глагол употребляется в форме инфинитива и отвечает на вопрос "что делать?", то нужно его писать с мягким знаком. Если же этот глагол употреблен в форме третьего лица настоящего времени и отвечает на вопрос "что делает?", то писать его нужно без мягкого знака.

Он может (что делать?) приходиться ему родственником?
Он (что делает?) точно приходится ему родственником.

*Хоть и живёшь в лесу, а дрова **приходится** покупать* (пословица).

*Сейчас гитлеровскому гарнизону совсем туго, дрова **приходится** покупать, а соответствующей статьи расхода в документах не предусмотрели.*
Д. Светлов. Снайпер разведотряда. Наш человек в ГРУ

Answer (score 1):

Для любителей казуистики. Ответ не столь однозначен, как может показаться с первого взгляда. Вот такое формально вполне законное построение, в котором присутствуют оба варианта:

**Им приходится покупать дрова, несмотря на то, что в деревню провели газ и им не должно приходиться покупать дрова.**

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **придется покупать дрова.**

ПРИЙТИСЬ, 3. **с инф. безл.** Стать неизбежным в связи с какими-л. обстоятельствами. **Придётся** ночевать именно здесь. **Пришлось** уступить просьбе.

В этом значении глагола используется **только безличная форма (не инфинитив).**

**Примечание:**

Принцип минимализма хорош во всем. Вот уж не надо никогда писать ничего лишнего (это я для себя).

И привет вам, М_Г! Вы были всегда так добры и снисходительны, нам вас, и ваших прекрасных качеств, и вашей любви к языку очень не хватает.

Comment: У *приходиться* нет буд. вр. (используется буду/будешь… приходиться), у *прийтись*  нет наст. вр.